# How to target individual CSS for different AutoComplete's ui-autocomplete

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have multiple AutoComplete's on a page.

When I use jQuery UI AutoComplete for all my text fields, it adds dynamic picklists of the form

```
<ul id="ui-id-1" tabindex="0" class="ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-autocomplete ui-front" style="top: 103px; left: 1678px; width: 256.828px; display: none;">
     <li class="ui-menu-item"><div id="ui-id-234" tabindex="-1" class="ui-menu-item-wrapper">Entry 1</div></li>
</ul>
```

There is a CSS style, `ui-autocomplete`, which I need to tweak differently for each field. But how to target **individual** `ui-autocomplete` choice boxes based on the DOM element they describe?

Why was it so difficult to add an attribute, such as `"domElement=myID"` to whatever picklist box generated, for easy targeting?

There is no positional before/after dependency I can rely on. Picklists are added at the bottom of the DOM.

Example of one of the AutoCompletes:

```
   $('#addModalUserSearch').autocomplete({

          source: function( request, response ) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "getAdminAddUserChoices",
                dataType: "json",
                type: "get",
                data: {
                    'term': request.term,
                    'org': $('#adminUserOrg').val()
                },
                success: function( data ) {
                      response ($.map (data, function (item) {
                          return {
                              label: item.value,  
                              value: item.key 
                          }
                      }));
                }
            });
          },
        minLength: 2,
        delay: 100,
        select: function(event, ui) { ..}
```

I need to do something like

```
.ui-autocomplete-1 {
     top: 120px !important;
     left: 80% !important;
}


.ui-autocomplete-2 {
     top: 5%;
     left: 60%;
}
```

Comment: Looks like you assign autocomplete based on IDs, so could try `#addModalUserSearch.ui-autocomplete` or can add a class via `classes` option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple ways to inject your own CSS when it comes to AutoComplete. Your post doesn't really show what you want, so I will try to be vague.

Consider the following:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#addModalUserSearch').autocomplete({
    classes: {
      "ui-autocomplete": "user-search"
    },
    source: function(request, response) {
      $.ajax({
        url: "getAdminAddUserChoices",
        dataType: "json",
        type: "get",
        data: {
          'term': request.term,
          'org': $('#adminUserOrg').val()
        },
        success: function(data) {
          response($.map(data, function(item) {
            return {
              label: item.value,
              value: item.key
            }
          }));
        }
      });
    },
    minLength: 2,
    delay: 100,
    select: function(event, ui) {
      //...
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.user-search {
  top: 120px !important;
  left: 80% !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="addModalUserSearch">User: </label>
  <input id="addModalUserSearch">
</div>
```

This example is essentially non-functional due to the remote source, yet you can still see the basic list generation:

```
<ul id="ui-id-1" tabindex="0" class="ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-autocomplete user-search ui-front" style="display: none;"></ul>
```

You can see the class `user-search` is listed and can be called and styled by CSS for this AutoComplete specifically.

You may also consider using the `position` option.

> **position** Type: Object, Default: `{ my: "left top", at: "left bottom", collision: "none" }`
>
> Identifies the position of the suggestions menu in relation to the associated input element. The of option defaults to the input element, but you can specify another element to position against. You can refer to the [jQuery UI Position utility](http://api.jqueryui.com/position/) for more details about the various options.

Another more complex way of doing this is to make use of the `_RenderMenu` Extension Point. Since AutoComplete uses Menu to build the selection list, you can tie into this to more deeply manage it's look.

> **_renderMenu( ul, items )**, Returns: jQuery (plugin only)
>
> Method that controls building the widget's menu. The method is passed an empty `<ul>` and an array of items that match the user typed term. Creation of the individual `<li>` elements should be delegated to `_renderItemData()`, which in turn delegates to the `_renderItem()` extension point.

Hope this helps.